# Insert a tzinfo into datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, tzinfo

I have the following `tzinfo` concrete subclass definition:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo

class ManilaTime(tzinfo):
  def utcoffset(self, dt):
    return timedelta(hours=8)

  def tzname(self, dt):
    return "Manila"
```

I obtain a date string and would like to transform it into a timezone-aware `datetime` object. I prefer to use the following method:

```
def transform_date(date_string, tzinfo):
  fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
  # Where do I insert tzinfo?
  date = datetime.strptime(date_string, fmt)
  return date
```

Is there some way I could insert the `tzinfo` into the `datetime` object in the following manner?

```
manila = ManilaTime()
date = transform_date('2001-01-01', manila)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
def transform_date(date_string, tzinfo):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
    date = datetime.strptime(date_string, fmt).replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)
    return date
```

Comment: fwiw, not to be used with pytz objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390097/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26266741/