# pytz and datetime weird behavior - possible bug?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pytz

I get the following output. Is this the intended behavior of pytz? I live in US/Eastern timezone, by the way. Why is EST giving -04:56 as the timezone offset?

```
import datetime
import pytz

a = datetime.datetime.now()
tz_est = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
a = a.replace(tzinfo=tz_est)
print("EST")
print(a)
print("\n")

b = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("US/Pacific"))
print("PST - version 1")
print(b)
print("\n")

tz_pst = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
c = tz_pst.normalize(a)
print("PST - version 2")
print(c)
print("\n")
```

EST
2017-03-16 22:52:27.616000-04:56

PST - version 1
2017-03-16 19:52:27.617000-07:00

PST - version 2
2017-03-16 20:48:27.616000-07:00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time zone field in isoformat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264897/time-zone-field-in-isoformat)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import pytz

a = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))
b = datetime.datetime.now()

pacific = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
c = pacific.localize(b)
d = pacific.normalize(a)

print(c)
print(d)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck here you go: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html

Answer (score 0):

Use zoneinfo instead of pytz to get the expected behavior.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

dt = datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles"))
```