# What do I have to do in Python to create an object which represents the January 1st, 2019 at 18:00 New York time (Eastern Time)?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, pytz

I am trying to define a datetime object which represents January 1st, 2019 at 18:00 New York time.

I try:

```
import datetime
import pytz
ts = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))
print(ts)
```

and I get:

```
2019-01-01 18:00:00-04:56
```

why -04:56?

I am using Python 3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pytz timezone function returns a timezone that is off by 9 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462876/python-pytz-timezone-function-returns-a-timezone-that-is-off-by-9-minutes)

Comment: I do not think it does answer the question, but I will defintiively change the question title. I am totally confused, how do I generate a specific timestamp of a given timezone? i.e. what do I ahve to do in Python to create an object which represents the January 1st, 2019 at 18:00 New York time (Easter Time).

Comment: This answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264897/time-zone-field-in-isoformat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time zone field in isoformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264897/time-zone-field-in-isoformat)

Answer (score 1):

This link ([Time zone field in isoformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264897/time-zone-field-in-isoformat)) provided by Victor in the comments above contains the answer.

I specifically include here the way to construct an object for a given timestamp.

```
eastern = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
print(eastern.localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 18)).isoformat())
```

Answer (score 0):

There tends to be problems using tzinfo with datetime constructors if the timezone has daylight savings transitions ([see here](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)). You could use the UTC timezone and convert to respective local times when displaying the time as a workaround.

Comment: My input data are timestamps from New York , if I understood you correctly you are saying ot store timestamps in UTC, what I want to store them with New York timestamps.